# Implementing Amdahl's Law

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

I am working on a homework assignment. I seem to be having difficulties applying Amdahl's Law. I feel as if I am working the problem out correct. Here is the question I am working on.

Suppose the daytime processing load consists of 60% CPU activity and 40% disk activity. Your customers are complaining that the system is slow. After doing
some research, you learn that you can upgrade your disks for $8,000 to make them 2.5 times as fast as they are currently. You have also learned that you can
upgrade your CPU to make it 1.4 times as fast for $5,000.

a. Which would you choose to yield the best performance improvement for the 
least amount of money?

b. Which option would you choose if you don't care about the money, but want a 
faster system?

c. What is the break-even point for the upgrades? That is, what price would we 
need to charge for the CPU (or the disk – change only one) so the result was 
the same cost per 1% increase for both?

I worked the formula and received the same amount of money for the 1% improvement. For the disk option i did, f=.4, k=2.5. When I plugged these numbers into the formula i got a speedup of 32%. For the CPU option, f=.6, k=1.4. I got a speed up of 20%. But the cost per 1% improvement, I am getting the same number of $250. Is my math off somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if perhaps this is simply a rounding error?

`SU(Disk) = 1.31579`

http://wolfr.am/102zBzb

`SU(CPU) = 1.2069`

http://wolfr.am/102zxiL

So I see where you got 32% and 20%, but you have rounded-up to get 32%, and rounded-down to get 20%. You'll notice if you try 32% and 21%, you get a different cost per 1% speed-up

Personally, I would probably use 31.6 and 20.7 (or even the full 31.579 and 20.69).

Comment: Oh ok. I see where I made my rounding mistakes. What I did was I round the f/k first then added it to the (1-f) part. Was only using a regular calculator so I wasn't able to enter in multiple expressions

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! I thought you might have accidentally forgot to round-up on the second value.